# How to combine "OR" query for different fields in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a "Dogs" collection like this:

```
Dogs: {
  dog1:{
    name: "Chiwawa"
    color: "Yellow",
    size: "Small"
  },
  dog2:{
    name: "Bulk"
    color: "Black",
    size: "Big"
  },
  dog3:{
    name: "Hunter"
    color: "Black",
    size: "Medium"
  },
  dog4:{
    name: "Wolf"
    color: "Gray",
    size: "Big"
  },
  dog5:{
    name: "Cute Chiwawa"
    color: "Black",
    size: "Medium"
  },
  ...
}
```

I want search the dogs by name, color and size, my query looks like this:

```
  var searchTerm = "Chiwawa";

  var query = dogsCollection
    .where("color", "in", ["Yellow", "Black", "White"])
    .where("size", "in", ["Medium", "Small"])
    .orderBy("name")
    .startAt(searchTerm)
    .endAt(searchTerm + "\uf8ff")
    .limit(2);
```

But due to firestore's limitation, I won't be able to use "in" twice so have to use something like querying by color and size separately and combine the results together (using Promise) but that won't solve the problem of pagination. Please give me the solution?

Comment: If you must use this document structure with pagination, you don't really have a solution.  Firestore can't do the query you want.

Comment: Do you have another workaround or a better document structure? just recommend me!

Answer (score 1):

Your only viable workaround is to store a single field that contains the composite data from the other two fields that you want to query together.  For example, you could have an array field called "size-color", which contains the concatenated values for each possible combination of size and color that would be true for the given dog.

So, if you had a dog that was "Small" and "Yellow", the value of the size-color field would be "Small-Yellow".  You would then query for that document using this filter:

```
.where("size-color", "in", ["Small-Yellow"])
```

Then, you can add more combinations:

```
.where("size-color", "in", ["Small-Yellow", "Small-Black", "Small-White"])
```

The problem is that you can only have 10 items with an `in` query, so you can see that this breaks down after a while.

Firestore is just not well suited for these kinds of queries.  You really should consider abandoning pagination if you want more flexible querying.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed might be a problem. I suggest to review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#node.js) about pagination in Firestore (if you haven't done it yet).

When I look at your use case it seems that you can convert this "size" to number value (Small: 1, Medium:2, Big: 3) and use it with where [Compound](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) queries using standard relational operators.

So in instead of:

```
.where("size", "in", ["Medium", "Small"])
```

you might use:

```
.where("size", "<", 3)
```

It isn't perfect, however it's possible to combine with where+"in" method.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but I will be grateful if you give me a more general answer in case of the selective fields other than "size". For example if the "Dogs" collection have one more field like: "foodType", the "foodType" can be one of ["bone", "meat", "cookie"..].